# Menu in WordPress, wp_nav_menu (); images with text on center

Tags: css, wordpress, image, menu

I'm trying to make a button menu using `wp_nav_menu()` but when I try to position the text, which is sometimes three or two lines of text, on the middle of the background image I cant align it vertically. When hovering over the link I wanted to add but it just doesn't want to seem to work.

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.menuButton ul {
    padding-top: 270px;        
}

.menuButton ul li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 145px;
    height: 140px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
}

.menuButton ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:  Open Sans;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    transition:.3s;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_0.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_1.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_2.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_3.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(5) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_4.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(6) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_5.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(7) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_6.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(8) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_7.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(9) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_8.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menuButton ul li:nth-of-type(10) {
    background: url(kafelki/k_9.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}
 .menuButton ul li a:hover {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: We will need to see your markup too, not just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `vertical-align: middle` and `line-height` in order to vertically align `inline-block` elements in a container. You just need to add a `span` inside your link in order to have the link on the whole button.

With this HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></span></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem ipsum</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS :

```
li {
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
li > a {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 100%;
}
li > a > span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwczkzm3/) illustrating this.

In order to add the span's inside your link tags, you can change the `link_before` and `link_after` parameters of your wp_nav_menu:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    // ... your current menu parameters ...
    'link_before' => '<span>',
    'link_after' => '</span>'
));
```